# x11vnc - Is it possible to send the intern sound of Host to Client?

Tags: audio, x11, vnc

I was wondering if there is a why to transmit the intern audio-sound of the host, which is running x11vnc to the client.

Didn't find anything  about it in the man page.

It would be cool to watch a video over VNC  (with sound) or listen to music.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible as part of VNC protocol, but you might be able to redirect your sound device - this is [example](http://ywwg.com/wordpress/?p=1201) for alsa

Comment: There is actually an extension called "QEMU Audio" - https://vncdotool.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/rfbproto.html#qemu-audio-client-message